# Xamarin Forms: Background timer stops in iOS when app is in background

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a step tracker application in xamarin forms which needs to give **update to server every 12am** about the number of  steps taken by the user. For this I have implemented timer as below.
It works fine in android but the **timer is stopped when the app is in background in iOS** **because of which we are not able to update at 12 am**

Please correct if anything else needs to be done in the code for iOS.

***Feel Free to  suggest any other native xamarin iOS solution also other than using timer to achieve this functionality.***

```
 public void TimeCalculation()
  {
            Timer execute;
            TimeSpan day = new TimeSpan(24, 00, 00);
            TimeSpan now = TimeSpan.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));    
            TimeSpan activationTime = new TimeSpan(12, 00, 00);    
            TimeSpan timeLeftUntilFirstRun = ((day - now) + activationTime);
            if (timeLeftUntilFirstRun.TotalHours > 24)
                timeLeftUntilFirstRun -= new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0);
            execute = new Timer();
            execute.Interval = timeLeftUntilFirstRun.TotalMilliseconds;
            execute.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(NewMethod);   
            execute.AutoReset = true;
            execute.Start();
    }


public async void NewMethod(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Device.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(async () =>
        {
            execute.Stop();
            //TODO
            TimeCalculation();
        });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: iOS does not let code arbitrarily execute in the background.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/ios-backgrounding-techniques/

Comment: @Jason Can you please suggest  if there is any other way around to achieve this functionality in iOS.

Comment: I just linked you to the official docs that explain all of iOS backgrounding options